# Using callback functions in vbscript

Tags: winapi, vbscript, callback

I'm trying to make an update script for windows7 in vbscript

when invoking [IUpdateSearcher::BeginSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) how do I pass the callback to [ISearchCompletedCallback::Invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

I'm just clueless on this points:

- do I need an function or sub or does this a custom object with an invoke method(and how to create)
- how I need to pass the callback
- is it even possible in vbscript (if not what is a good next step?)

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you've got so far?

Comment: its a modification of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387102(v=vs.85).aspx , but being clueless i did not try anything

Comment: this is what i have got so far http://pastebin.com/PqQhZ0XG

Answer (score 1):

VBscript does not deal well with callbacks.

I've been working with the [BeginSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-beginsearch), [BeginDownload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatedownloader-begindownload) and [BeginInstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdateinstaller-begininstall) for a while, and the solution is to use any object descendant of **iUnknown** and ignore it for the rest of the code.

You will have to use the **IsCompleted** property of the returned objects [iSearchJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-isearchjob), [iDownloadJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-idownloadjob) or [iInstallationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-iinstallationjob), to verify that the operation has been completed, before calling **EndSearch**, **EndDownload** or **EndInstall** to finish the operation and retrieve valid results.

You should also implement a timeout function to terminate each operation if it has been running for too long.

Here is a simple example that works (run it with CScript):

```
Dim strChars
    strChars = "-+|+"
If InStr(LCase(WScript.FullName),"cscript.exe") = 0 Then 
    WScript.Echo "This script requires to be run using CScript.exe"    
    WScript.Quit
End If
Set objUpdateSearcher = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session").CreateUpdateSearcher()
WScript.Echo "Searching for new updates ..."
Set objSearchJob = objUpdateSearcher.BeginSearch ("", WScript , vbNull)
Do Until objSearchJob.IsCompleted
    WScript.Sleep 200
    WScript.StdOut.Write GetProgress & vbCr
Loop
Set objSearchResult = objUpdateSearcher.EndSearch (objSearchJob)
If objSearchResult.ResultCode = 2 Then
    If objSearchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "No new updates."
    ElseIf objSearchResult.Updates.Count = 1 Then
        WScript.Echo "A new update is available."
    Else 
        WScript.Echo objSearchResult.Updates.Count & " new updates available."
    End If
Else
    WScript.Echo "Error while searching updates (Code: 0x" & Hex(objSearchResult.ResultCode) & ")"
End If
Function GetProgress
    GetProgress = Left(strChars,1)
    strChars = Right(strChars,Len(strChars)-1) & Left(strChars,1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but I'd look at the [ConnectObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccxe1xe6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Method.
This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564) about scripting events might also be useful.

So maybe something like this (complete guess):

```
Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
WScript.ConnectObject objSearcher, "searcherCallBack_"
objSearcher.BeginSearch ...


sub searcherCallBack_Invoke()
    ' handle the callback
end sub
```

I'd also suggest reading [Guidelines for Asynchronous WUA Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385820%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to make sure that you clean up after yourself.
that link also mentions using `Windows Script Host`, so it should definitely be possible to do this, though unless you need it to be asynchronous, the synchronous methods wouls probably be a easier.

Comment: thanks looks promessing, i'll let you know tonight when i'm home

Comment: it sees i not need to connect to UpdateSearcher, but to a (new?) interface called ISearchCompletedCallback and pass it as arg?   (b.t.w. i updated the links sorry)(also check my paste)

Comment: VBScript targets Automation interface (IDispatch, IProvideClassInfo and all that jazz). I don't think this will work with IUpdateSearcher. (more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/09/21/472465.aspx)

Comment: ok what about this (from msdn) `As an alternative to implementing the ISearchCompletedCallback interface, you can use a script to implement a callback routine of any identifier with DISPID 0 on an automation object. The type of the onCompleted parameter is IUnknown*.` can dispid be controlled(late state binding??) form vbscript

Comment: @borrel: Sounds promising, but as I said, I've never actually tried it so I'm afraid I can't give any better help.